# Core Data not returning results on one device, working on all others

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I have to devices here, both equipped with my core data application. The problem is, when I build it for device (development build), and sync it with iTunes to my 3 devices (2 iPhones 3GS and an iPad), the application works correct on one iPhone and the iPad.
On the other one, it doesn't return records (from a prepopulated sqlite database).

The device on which it is not working is not set up as development device, the other two are, but the correct profiles are installed and the application runs except for not fetching the records.

Any ideas because I've never seen anything like this before.
I've tried a restore with no success.

**Solution:**
I could not figure out what the cause was, but a restore and a setup as new device solved my problem.
The fact that all data in the backup was lost did not matter since it was a demonstration device and did not contain any important data created by using it.

Comment: I think that this may be because you have it set as a development build. If you change it to release build, what happens?

Comment: I'm sorry I read this too late. I've solved it by setting up the device as a new device instead of restoring the backup. It works correct now even when it is a development build.